# Loading additional core extensions with TYPO3 and nimut testing framework

Tags: phpunit, typo3

I try to write some functional tests for an extension of mine. I have a test that submits a database query on table sys_file_metadata. I got an error, that the table sys_file_metadata could not be found.

For the test I use TYPO3 8.7.10 and the nimut testing framework.

This is my test class without the actual tests:

```
use Nimut\TestingFramework\TestCase\FunctionalTestCase;

class FileRepositoryTest extends FunctionalTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @var FileRepository
     */
    protected $fileRepository;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $coreExtensionsToLoad = ['filemetadata'];

    /**
     * @throws \Nimut\TestingFramework\Exception\Exception
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
        $this->fileRepository = $this->objectManager->get(FileRepository::class);

        $this->importDataSet(__DIR__ . '/../Fixtures/sys_file.xml');
        $this->importDataSet(__DIR__ . '/../Fixtures/sys_file_metadata.xml');
    }
}
```

Maybe I forget something to declare. The extension filemetadata gets loaded, but the ext_tables.sql seems to be ignored.

I excluded some use statements, that I think are not important for this case. Also the actual test case is not included because I think the problem is the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you mind to share the concrete error message? Database table sys_file_metadata gets created from core extension always for every test case. Just without the additional fields from filemetadata extension.

Comment: This is the error message I get:

Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT `sys_file`.*, `sys_file_metadata`.* FROM `sys_file` INNER JOIN `sys_file_metadata` `metadata` ON `metadata`.`file` = `sys_file`.`uid` WHERE `sys_file_metadata`.`image_compression_status` = ? ORDER BY `sys_file`.`tstamp` ASC LIMIT 1' with params [0]:

Unknown table 'sys_file_metadata'

Comment: I created a custom query to check for field image_compression_status and use a join for that. I know that this query works, when using it in a scheduler task.

Comment: It seems the data import in `$this->importDataSet(__DIR__ . '/../Fixtures/sys_file_metadata.xml');` seems to work then. I would guess that some database configuration is mixed up.

Comment: You set up an alias `metadata` for the sys_file_metadata in your query. You have to make sure this alias is used in the whole statement.

Comment: Oh my god, you're  right (like your nickname already says). I'm using the Doctrine query builder to build the query for TYPO3 v8 and there you have to use an alias for joins. But I was missing to use the alias for my matching field in the where-clause ...

Comment: But it's odd, that the query works when using it in a scheduler task  Never than less, the test now works :) Thank you very much